# Play 2.7.x: ProvisionException: Unable to provision play.api.Application with circular dependencies

Tags: scala, playframework

From Play 2.7.x I'm unable to get hold of the `play.api.Application`, I have tried multiple ways e.g. from a custom module (plugin) or even from my `ApplicationController`. I always get the following circular dependencies error:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Found a circular dependency involving play.api.Application, and circular dependencies are disabled.
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:252)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
    for the 10th parameter of controllers.ApplicationController.<init>(ApplicationController.scala:30)
  while locating controllers.ApplicationController
    for the 2nd parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:111)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for the 3rd parameter of play.api.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:120)
  while locating play.api.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for the 6th parameter of play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:253)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:252)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error
```

For example, from my custom module `DynamicTemplateLoader`:

```
@Singleton
class DynamicTemplateLoader @Inject(app: play.api.Application) {
   ...
}
```

or from my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController @Inject() (
  components: ControllerComponents
)(
  implicit app: play.api.Application
) extends AbstractController(components) with I18nSupport {
   ...
}
```

Why do I need the `play.api.Application`? I need to get hold of the `app.classloader` to use reflection from my plugin.

Comment: but why `app.classloader`? wouldn't the `classloader` be same irrespective of which instance you get it from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by switching from injecting an instance of `play.api.Application` to instead injecting an instance of `javax.inject.Provider[play.api.Application]`.